# Unable to migrate contracts onto private network (Insufficient funds)

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, private-blockchain, truffle-migration

I'm trying to migrate a number of contracts onto a private network I've stood up, but I keep getting this error when I run my `truffle migrate`

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

I definitely have funds (upwards of 3000 ether, so I'm private network rich), so I can't figure out why I'm having this issue.

Here is a snippet of my deploy script:

```
deployer.deploy(Logger, { gas: 5000000, gasPrice: 1000000, from: '0xcd53d707046431992698e2046f16430c4175694f' })
```

I've tried a number of different gas and gasPrice values in my deploy script, I've tried gas values ranging from 1-5 million, and gasPrice values from 1000000 to 1000000000. That account is definitely my etherbase account, as its balance continues to go up.

My private network is running on geth, and I run it with this command (after running a geth init and setting up the db).

`geth --mine --minerthreads 1 --targetgaslimit 8000000 --gasprice "100000" --rpc`

Here is my genesis file:

```
{
    "config": {
      "chainId": 0,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "nonce": "0x02475A7325B73425",
    "timestamp": "0x0",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "gasLimit": "0x7a1200",
    "difficulty": "0x400",
    "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
    "alloc": {
    }
}
```

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because I found the answer (though it was around sending funds, not migrating contracts. Changing "chainId" to a non-zero value fixed my issue.